# iMac does not respond to any key at boot

Tags: boot, mac, keyboard

My [iMac of late 2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmD92.jpg) with a 3.1 GHz Quad-Core i7 processor and 16GB memory **doesn't respond to any key combination during boot**!
I have tried an old Mac USB keyboard as the usual keyboard is Bluetooth (both shown in the picture). I must mention that the iMac is running Big Sur, which doesn't officially support this old Mac, after an earlier successful patch following the instructions from [this page](https://macresearch.org/big-sur-on-unsupported-mac/). Any ideas as to what I can do? I can't even reinstall its original OS. I must - at least - start with *cmd+R* the recover page.

Comment: Can you get to the desktop at all? Does it respond later in the process, or are you locked out completely? Do you have another Mac you can work from?

Comment: Have you tried unplugging all other USB devices, including hubs and port expanders, and just having your USB keyboard plugged in? I'm wondering if something else is fouling your USB bus. As for Bluetooth, you must press the keys as the boot chime is trailing off; hitting them too early will cause them to be ignored.